# Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4a wifi dropouts and disconnects

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a PC with an Asus Z270E Gaming Mobo, and it runs the Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4a wireless adapter. I've had this computer for about 2 or 3 years, and recently I've been having frequent issues with it losing the signal and will completely disconnect from the router on 5Ghz. After running the troubleshooter, it will usually give me the error of "Default Gateway not found," or recently it's also then given me the weird error that an ethernet cable is not connected.

I've tried a number of solutions by the wisdom of the internet, but all to no success. I've tried a static connection, switching to 2.4Ghz (which gets rid of disconnects, but the signal still will completely drop for a period of time), I've tried refreshing my BIOS, uninstalling the device and resetting, renewing DHCP lease. I even rolled back the driver, and had temporary success, but after about a day it went back to the same issue all over again no matter what driver I use.

I've tried just about everything short of refreshing Windows or doing a clean install, which is not really an option as I've seen many reports that it doesn't work, and that's a lot of work for something that isn't a guaranteed success, and based on location, a wired connection is pretty much not an option.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have a Inspiron 5505. When downloading a big file I lose the Wifi connection after some time.